# Scaling mysql in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm looking to scale mysql on a swarm that could potentially be involve multiple servers. What is the best way to ensure that the data is in sync between the containers on the different servers?

I realise on a standard configuration without docker I'd have to set up replication. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it which is more suitable and easy to deploy with docker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Docker-compose and docker swarm` are great tool for scaling in docker environments. But Currently 
`MySQL-DB scaling is not possible in docker-compose or docker-swarm`. Reasons:

- Scaling fit for stateless containers
- Configuration not possible for master-slave in docker-swarm
- No replication method available in docker overlay network

May be in future we have such tech to enable RDBMS scaling.

Comment: What about such services as Redis? If we speak only about caching (not pub-sub and other Redis staff), it will be possible to get misses after reconnection, yes? Just if load balancer will decide to switch you yo another node...

Comment: I did not test it, yet, but what about a galera cluster? This should run most mysql applications. An implementation: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/mariadb-galera-swarm

Comment: What if I try to scale mysql within single machine with a volume created. I have created one volume on the host and expecting all the replicated mysql container to use same but not achieved so far.

Comment: @Tara Prasad, then what's the use of scaling when you are running on single machine only.

Comment: Actually we have one good enough machine and we are trying to scale the containers within it. @ManojSahu

Comment: is it for production or testing?

Answer (score 1):

This is what database replication is for.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

Comment: That's how I'd definitely do it in a non Dockerized environment. I was just wondering if there was a way more specific to containers of doing it.

Comment: @kevin.coyle: I don't see why it should be any different inside Docker.

Comment: This answer seems so 1930's to me :-)  While I agree this is what database replication is for, come 'on, if we have that in a Docker Swarm and the main instance goes down, can the switch over be automatic?  Enquiring minds want to know...

Comment: @JoeG: It is automatic! Better, it's implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mariadb galera cluster, setup under docker, however you need other steps to provision and load balancer, and a node monitors the state of your containers (many works and it's not easy)
And, if you have multiple Nodes on docker swarm, your need to setup NFS server for docker to share files.
There is a tool called Cluster Control, free and paid version
https://severalnines.com/product/clustercontrol/docker-mysql-database-management